# Inserting with empty string in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i am new in cakePHP framework with version 2.0 my problem is when i save the data or insert the new record the field is empty or no data to be save how can i fix this. .

**My Model**

```
class Post extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'posts';
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public function add(){
   if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Post->create();
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The posts was saved');
            $this->redirect('index');
        }       
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Create Posts');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Posts');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the validation rules in the `Post` model, Then you can check validate data or not in the controller action before `save` into model. See the following `Model` and `controller`

**In Model**

```
class Post extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'posts';

    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'This is can'\t blank'
            ),

        ),
        'body' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'This is can'\t blank'
            ),            
        ),
    );
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function add(){
   if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Post->create();
        $this->Post->set($this->request->data);

        if ($this->Post->validates()) {
        // it validated logic
            if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('The posts was saved');
                $this->redirect('index');
            }
        } else {
            // didn't validate logic
            $errors = $this->Post->validationErrors;
        }       
    }
}
```